# Codeacademy: Loops and Arrays 2 (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with my code working on CodeAcademy. I have compared it to other people who have passed this section and I can not find the mistake.

I keep getting "SyntaxError: Missing ) after argument list"

```
var names = ["Andy", "Paige", "Damian", "Aaron", "Carrie"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++)
{
    console.log("I know someone called " names[i])
}
```

//Does anybody have any idea why?

Comment: The log needs to be either `console.log("I know someone called ", names[i])` or `console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! It's always something so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a + sign to concatenate a string and variable. Change your console.log to

`console.log("I know someone called " + names[i])`

Comment: Thank you very much! It's always that one little thing that I miss that breaks the entire code!

Comment: @andywb26 No worries Andy. Good luck using code academy. It was really useful when I started to learn :).

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to concatenate the string to variable

```
console.log("I know someone called "+ names[i])
```